# existe alguma função em javascript, php ou xml para ocultar ou bloquear os botões da barra de titulo dos nagedores

Tags: php, javascript

estou fazendo uma página para validar um item porém eu gostaria que esta pagina só fechasse se o item escaneado tiver certo até ai funciona, porem não conseguir encontrar nenhum código para ocultar ou bloquear os botões da barra de titulo das janelas dos navegadores pois eu gostaria que o usuário não pudesse fechar a janela alguém conhece um formula de fazer isso em alguma linguagem web.

```
<script>     
function valid(){
 var grupo   = $("#grupo").val();
 var certo   = $("#certo").val();
 var familia = $("#familia").val();

    if(window.event.keyCode == 13){
        if(grupo != certo){
            document.getElementById('fail').style.display = "block";
            $("#grupo").val('');
        }else if(familia == 'T46S' || familia == 'T470' || familia == 'T480'){
            document.getElementById('kit').style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById('kit2').style.display = "block";
            $("#kit2").focus();
            document.getElementById('grupo').style.display = "none";
        }else{
            window.open('', '_self', '');
            window.close();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: você não consegue impedir todas as ações do usuário, e nem seria recomendável, aposto que não gostaria se um site ocultasse os botões da barra do seu navegador :)
apenas para ilustrar, `xml` não é uma linguagem, portanto não possui comandos ou ações, as ações para intervir no navegador do usuário são feitas com `Javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Impedir completamente o usuário não é possivel. Você pode fazer uma pergunta para ele por exemplo.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e)

setTimeout(function() {
   $("#modal_24").modal("show");
}, 10);

var msg = "Antes de sair gostaria de responder a nossa pesquisa?";
e = e || window.event;

// Pro IE e Firefox anterior a versão 4
if (e) {
    e.returnValue = msg;
}

// Para Safari e Chrome
return msg;
```

}